# Syncing outlook PST data to exchange server?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, pst

One of our users removed his exchange account (using our control panel - dotnetpanel). Fortunately, he had everything cached local in his outlook.
I know have a PST file of 900MB containing some +2000 contacts and a lot of emails. Question is, how do we sync it back to his newly created exchange account?
Protocol is NOT imap/pop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. One possible way could be to use [pst to imap injection](http://wildness.espix.org/index.php?post/2009/11/17/Inject-Outlook-PST-Archives-files-into-IMAP-account)
You first allow IMAP on your exchange, and then use the mentioned method.